# Laravel middleware for different role user in a same table

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4. In my apps, there are two kind of user. Normal and admin. Normal or admin is decided by role column. Now I want to protect some page for user. I can protect any page using `auth`. But it only protect without logged in user. How I can protect some page for user? and give access to the admin only. Sorry for my poor English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a middleware that checks that role column on the authenticated user.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer